# 401 Unauthorizied Error in Postman using Spring Boot App

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, postman, unauthorized

I'm trying to implement a JWT token using Spring Boot, this is my WebSecurityConfiguration:

```
 @Autowired
  private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;


  @Autowired
  private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;



  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsService jwtService;
  @Autowired
  public void setJwtAuthenticationEntryPoint(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint) {
    this.jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint = jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
  }

  @Autowired
  public void setJwtRequestFilter(JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter) {
    this.jwtRequestFilter = jwtRequestFilter;
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
    AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
    return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
  }


  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.cors();
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
      .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers ("/authenticate").permitAll()
      .requestMatchers (HttpHeaders.ALLOW).permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
      .and()
      .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return httpSecurity.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(jwtService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  }
```

My JwtRequest looks like this:

```
public class JwtRequest {

  private String username;
  private String password;

  public JwtRequest(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }
}
```

The Service:

```
@Service
public class JwtService implements UserDetailsService {


  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;
  @Autowired
  private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  public JwtResponse createJwtToken(JwtRequest jwtRequest) throws Exception{
    String username = jwtRequest.getUsername();
    String password = jwtRequest.getPassword();
    authenticate(username,password);

    final UserDetails userDetails = loadUserByUsername(username);
    String newGeneratedToken =  jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

    User user = userRepository.findById(username).get();

    return new JwtResponse(user,newGeneratedToken);
  }

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user =  userRepository.findById(username).get();

    if(user != null) {
      return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(),user.getUserPassword(),getAuthorities(user));
    }
    else {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username is not valid");
    }
  }

  private Set getAuthorities(User user){
    Set authorities = new HashSet();

    user.getRole().forEach(role -> {
      authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getRoleName()));
    });
    return authorities;
  }

  private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception{
    try{
      authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,password));
    }
      catch (DisabledException e) {
      throw new Exception("User is disabled");
      } catch(BadCredentialsException e) {
      throw new Exception("Bad credentials for user");
    }
  }
}
```

And the Controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class JwtController {

  @Autowired
  private JwtService jwtService;


  @PostMapping({"/authenticate"})
  public JwtResponse createJwtToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest jwtRequest) throws Exception {
    return jwtService.createJwtToken(jwtRequest);

  }
}
```

I tried to test the createJwtToken method with Postman, so I sent a post request with the url http://localhost:8080/authenticate  (my app is running on port 8080) and with the body (raw + json)
{
"username": "admin123",
"password": "admin@pass"
}

I created this username and this password in my UserService file and I know they are right because I did a select on my table in MySQL and I got this values.

I get a 401 Unauthorized error and I dont know why, or what could I do?

Answer (score -1):

This is my security config. You can try this.

```
    @Override
        
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                
   http.csrf().disable().cors()
.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);     
    }

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth_token"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem was with my Secret Key, it was too short